# How do I make my table go over two pages?

Tags: tables

I see people use the longtable environment but when i try to use it, I still have my 'begin tabular' in my table, and it doesnt work.

This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7}\textit{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Type of Limitation \& \\ Weaknesses\end{tabular}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7}\textit{\textbf{Impact on Data}}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7}\textit{\textbf{Improvements}}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         \\ \hline
\textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Systematic:\\ Limited Temperature\\ Range\end{tabular}}                                                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The narrow temperature range may\\ limit the generalizability of the\\ findings to a wider range of \\ temperature conditions. The observed \\ relationship between temperature and\\ Vitamin C concentration may not\\ accurately reflect the behavior at \\ extreme temperatures or within \\ intermediate temperature ranges.\end{tabular}                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}To address this limitation, future \\ experiments can include a broader\\  spectrum of temperatures, including\\ extreme values and additional \\ intermediate points.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \hline
\textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Systematic:\\ Sensitivity to \\ Environmental \\ Factors\end{tabular}}                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Uncontrolled environmental factors, \\ such as light exposure, air oxidation, \\ and pH fluctuations, can introduce \\ additional sources of variation and \\ impact the observed relationship \\ between temperature and Vitamin C\\  concentration.\end{tabular}                                                                                           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}To address this limitation, future \\ experiments should consider\\ controlling and monitoring \\ environmental factors. This can be\\ achieved by conducting the \\ experiment in a controlled \\ laboratory environment, using \\ light-blocking containers, employing\\ inert gas purging techniques to \\ minimize oxidation,and implementing \\ pH adjustment and monitoring to \\ maintainconsistent acidity levels \\ throughout the experiment. By \\ controlling these factors, the \\ experiment can isolate the specific \\ effects of temperature on Vitamin C\\ concentration more accurately.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Systematic:\\ Time Dependency\end{tabular}}                                                              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The experiment may not have \\ accounted for the potential \\ time-dependent degradation of \\ Vitamin C in lemon juice. It is\\ possible that the observed \\ changes in concentration were\\ influenced by the duration of \\ exposure to different temperatures\\ rather than temperature alone.\end{tabular}                                             & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}To overcome this limitation, future\\ experiments can incorporate a \\ time-dependent analysis. By exposing\\ the lemon juice samples to different \\ temperatures for specific durations and\\ tracking the changes in Vitamin C \\ concentration over time, a more \\ comprehensive understanding of the\\ relationship between temperature \\ and time can be achieved.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \hline
\textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Random:\\ Error in Titration \\ Measurements\end{tabular}}                                               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Random errors in the titration \\ measurements, such as slight \\ variations in the volume of \\ titrant added or imprecise endpoint \\ determination, can introduce \\ random variation in the recorded\\ Vitamin C concentrations.\\  Additionally, inspection when taking\\ measurements from conical flasks \\ can result in further error.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}To minimize random errors in \\ titration measurements, careful \\ attention should be paid to technique \\ and precision. Using proper pipetting \\ techniques, ensuring accurate volume \\ measurements, and conducting multiple \\ trials can help reduce the impact of \\ random errors and improve the reliability \\ of the results.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

In the picture, I am trying to get the table up on the whitespace above.

Comment: Use `\begin{longtable}`; not `\begin{tabular}`. (And be sure to read the documentation: https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf.) Note: you should provide an MWE and not just a code snippet.

Comment: Also, do not put `longtable` inside a `table` (float) environment.

Answer (score 1):

A `tabular` environment cannot span more than one page. I suggest you employ a [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) environment instead. I would also like to recommend that you give the table a much more open "look," by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines. And, switch to a column type (such as `p`) that allows automatic line breaking, and get rid of the `tabular` wrappers and hard line breaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1\textwidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ L{.23} L{.31} L{.35} }

\rowcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7} 
\textit{\textbf{Type of Limitation$^{\strut}$ \& Weaknesses}} 
& \textit{\textbf{Impact on Data}} 
& \textit{\textbf{Improvements}} \\ 
\addlinespace
\endhead

\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\footnotesize continued on next page}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\textit{Systematic: Limited Temperature Range}
& The narrow temperature range may limit the generalizability of the findings to a wider range of temperature conditions. The observed relationship between temperature and Vitamin~C concentration may not accurately reflect the behavior at extreme temperatures or within intermediate temperature ranges.    
& To address this limitation, future experiments can include a broader spectrum of temperatures, including extreme values and additional intermediate points.                                                                                                          
\\ \addlinespace

\textit{Systematic: Sensitivity to Environmental Factors}         
& Uncontrolled environmental factors, such as light exposure, air oxidation, and pH fluctuations, can introduce additional sources of variation and impact the observed relationship between temperature and Vitamin~C concentration.                       
& To address this limitation, future experiments should consider controlling and monitoring environmental factors. This can be achieved by conducting the experiment in a controlled laboratory environment, using light-blocking containers, employing inert gas purging techniques to minimize oxidation, and implementing pH adjustment and monitoring to maintain consistent acidity levels throughout the experiment. By controlling these factors, the experiment can isolate the specific effects of temperature on Vitamin~C concentration more accurately. 
\\ 
\addlinespace

\textit{Systematic: Time Dependency}
& The experiment may not have accounted for the potential time-dependent degradation of Vitamin~C in lemon juice. It is possible that the observed changes in concentration were influenced by the duration of exposure to different temperatures rather than temperature alone.            
& To overcome this limitation, future experiments can incorporate a time-dependent analysis. By exposing the lemon juice samples to different temperatures for specific durations and tracking the changes in Vitamin~C concentration over time, a more comprehensive understanding of the relationship between temperature and time can be achieved.                                                         
\\ \addlinespace

\textit{Random: Error in Titration Measurements}
& Random errors in the titration measurements, such as slight variations in the volume of titrant added or imprecise endpoint determination, can introduce random variation in the recorded Vitamin~C concentrations. Additionally, inspection when taking measurements from conical flasks can result in further error. 
& To minimize random errors in titration measurements, careful attention should be paid to technique and precision. Using proper pipetting techniques, ensuring accurate volume measurements, and conducting multiple trials can help reduce the impact of random errors and improve the reliability of the results.                                                                 
\\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this is a beautiful table. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I have another problem. When I use the relevant preambles, it makes my heading to my title page have a lot of space between itself, do you know how I make that go away? code:   
\begin{titlepage}
\raggedleft
\rule{1pt}{\textheight}
 \hspace{0.05\textwidth} 
 \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{ 
{\Huge\bfseries Investigating the Physical Pendulum}\\[2\baselineskip] % Title
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
}
\end{titlepage}

Comment: @NealBatra - For a new question, please post a new query. Thanks. (By the way, your code snippet is *not compilable*, in part because you don't indicate which document class you employ.)